# Convert postgresql ~* as ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is this the correct way to convert postgresql `~*` syntax in ecto? When I convert the ecto back into SQL, it is different. It uses `or's` instead of the original `~*`

SQL

```
SELECT
    col1,
    FROM table1
    WHERE col1 ~* 'AAA|bbb|CcC'
```

Ecto

```
from (t1 in table1,
where: ilike(t1.col1, "AAA") or ilike(t1.col1, "bbb") or ilike(t1.col1, "CcC"),
select: %{
 col1: t1.col1
}
```

The Ecto gets converted back as ORs like so instead of the original `WHERE col1 ~* 'AAA|bbb|CcC'`

```
where
    ((sssp0."col1" ilike 'AAA')
    or (sssp0."col1" ilike 'bbb'))
    or (sssp0."col1" ilike 'CcC'))
```

Is this the same?

Comment: Would not `where: fragment("col1 ~* ?", "AAA|bbb|CcC")` work? [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1).

Comment: yes, but was thinking it would be better to use the ecto API's instead of relying on fragments

Comment: ecto api is a general implementation, that is guaranteed to work across different databases, this operator is specific only to postgres so you won't be able to create this exact query without fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to speak for the Ecto maintainers, but I believe this isn't included in the standard function set because covering *all* of the functionality that a database provides would be a virtual nightmare to maintain (I assume). You can, however, create your own API convenience functions to wrap the Postgres operators using fragments under the covers with macros.

In your case, you could create your own API module:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.QueryAPI do
  defmacro iregex(left, right) do
    quote do: fragment("? ~* ?", unquote(left), unquote(right))
  end
end
```

And in the module you want to use it:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Logic do
  import Ecto.Query
  import MyApp.QueryAPI

  def reg_search(term) do
    MyApp.Model.Something
    |> where([s], iregex(s.name, ^term))
    |> MyApp.Repo.all()
  end
end
```

This is a really neat example of how extensible Ecto really is. I use convenience fragment wrappers all the time to make things more readable and DRY.